# Flutter is unable to locate android sdk

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-manager

I just tried installing flutter and since I already have android studio and the android sdk installed I just followed the flutter installation instructions but I keep getting the result below whenever I run flutter doctor.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7NaD.jpg)
I already tried reinstalling the sdk but it did not work.
I'll be very thankful for any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this..

```
flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>
```

Comment: have you set the default paths?
....    
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\<installation location>\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an Environment variable to you Android SDk path
Search in windows for env -> Environment variable -> new

[image: Environment variable]

Comment: @Richard Can you create an android project in Android Studio and run it on an emulator? if it shows you any errors please share it with us

Comment: It  returns  ' unable to locate development device'

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest build tools in Android SDK Manager -> SDK Tools
[image]

And the latest SDK Platform (Android API 30)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if Android SDK Build-Tools, Android SDK Platform-Tools & Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) are installed?

If you still have the problem, do a fresh installation of Android Studio but remove all old Android folders beforehand.

Comment: They have been installed